# Extracting Decision Tree from Given Data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

I have the below image only (not the dataset that represents this image) and I need to draw the decision tree that represents this data in the graph.
[image]

I made a research and I'm thinking it that I should be starting from blue crosses and apply the rules that if -4<x1<4 and 0<x2<4 then moving to green diamonds and else moving to red circles. But I'm not sure if I'm correct. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right. Your decision tree here looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey @maria, thank you for your answer. Do you think I could improve the result if I used random forest instead?

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused, what is your task here. Do you have to understand the data model and draw a decision tree manually (like I draw this using http://draw.io/)? Or you have to get the decision tree automatically (i.e. using sklearn, but you'll need the actual dataset for this task)? And speaking about the random forest, actually, it is a bunch of trees. In this case, you will get (for example) 10 trees to draw.